# We need to run a repeat notification every day 7am and the content is dynamic

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

We need to run a repeat notification every day 7 am and the content is not static it is dynamic

content needs to fetch from API

is there any way to do it in flutter for both ios and android

With out doing anything from server-side?

We used https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications and not solved the issue?

We are developing an app for an existing website and clients have all the APIs and they are not using FCM. They will not do any changes in server-side and they highly recommend to handle it's from the app side only.

If we use Firebase messaging lib is that possible to do notification and API call in background with in the ios and android app?

Answer (score 0):

Use firebase functions with pubsub. Use this code in the firebase function.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const fcm = admin.messaging();

    exports.dailyNotification = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 7 * * *')
    
    .onRun((context) => {
        //tokens need to be unique to send notifications per device
        //you can call data from firebase firestore to change the notification contents
    
        const payload = admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
                            
            notification: {
                title: 'Notification title',
                body: 'This is a notification message',
                icon: 'your-icon-url',
                click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
            }
        };
       /*this token you need to save from flutter. You need it only when you 
         need to send specific notification to the specific device*/

        fcm.sendToDevice(tokens.token, payload);
    
    });
```

Use this package in flutter
[Firebase messaging lib](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/install)

Learn it from here that how to use firebase messaging notification.
[Flutter firebase notification tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If we use  Firebase messaging lib can we handle the notification from app side? Is it need any backend code ?

Comment: You can use local notification package then. But I think using firebase backend will solve all the problems. You can identify the users and what notification needs to be sent in the backend easily using firebase function.

Comment: what I have to do if I want to repeat weekly?

Comment: @AlMamun You can set daily then manually check if the day is the new week or not.